# create an class element returns nothing

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart

tI am trying to create a stream from my firestore and convert it to my class modal.
here is the stream:

```
     Stream<List<ChatRoom>> getChatRooms({required UnicoUser user}){
    return chatCollection.where("usersId", arrayContains: user.uid).snapshots().map((event) => event.docs.map((data) {
      Map<String, dynamic> chatRoomData = data.data() as Map<String, dynamic>;
      print(chatRoomData);
      List<String> userId = chatRoomData["usersId"];
      int unreadNumber =chatRoomData["unreadNumber"];
      String sender =chatRoomData["sender"];
      String text =chatRoomData["text"];
      ChatRoom chat = ChatRoom(sender: sender ,text: text, time: DateTime.parse(chatRoomData["time"].toDate().toString()),
          usersId: userId,unreadNumber:unreadNumber );
      print(chat.text);
      print(chat);
       return chat;
    }).toList());
  }
```

The class instance creation return always null:

```
I/flutter ( 9616): {unreadNumber: 0, sender: V2BrKcksrNS5W7qBKgkn9LY4dhl1, usersId: [V2BrKcksrNS5W7qBKgkn9LY4dhl1, GTqv78azASXT8HW6iem2m6ApZJe2], time: Timestamp(seconds=1638649472, nanoseconds=582000000), text: last}
I/flutter ( 9616): No Data
```

here is the class:

```
class ChatRoom{
  List<String> usersId;
  String text;
  DateTime time;
  int unreadNumber;
  String sender;

  ChatRoom({required this.text, required this.sender, this.unreadNumber = 0, required this.time, required this.usersId});

  @override
  String toString() {
    return "Chat room: [Text: $text, Time: ${time.toString()}]";
  }
}
```

I checked if all the values are valid and attempted to create generic instance in the same function which worked.
thanks
Oz

Comment: 1. You have three `print` statements but only two lines of output. 2. There's nothing in the printed response that indicates that anything is the `null` value. 3. If `chat.text` is expected to contain the value passed via `ChatRoom(..., text: text)` but doesn't, then the problem is with your `ChatRoom` constructor, which you haven't shown.

Comment: I added the constructor, but as i mentioned above the constructor worked on generic instance at the same function..

Comment: Could you please address points 1 and 2 from my comment?

Comment: Yes that’s exactly the problem, I don’t know why is the print statements doesn’t presents outputs that’s why I thought the instance I have created is null

Comment: Your `print` statements should execute unconditionally.  If one prints, all three should print.  If you're seeing only two lines of output, that output is coming from different `print` statements (or from a different version of your code).

Comment: yes that's exactly the problem.. the no data print statement comes from the streamProvider  which gets nothing from the getChatRooms func

Comment: i do not understand why all my print statements does not executes and why the stream returns nothing..

Comment: That shouldn't be possible.  As I stated, either you're observing output from different `print` statements than you think, or you're executing a program that doesn't match the version of the code you've posted.  Please post a reproducible example.